# Laravel: if user login then logout option does not showing in menu bar

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel and Issue is that after a successful login there is no logout option show in the menu bar.Login option still show after login user.Please help me to solve this issue.Thank you!

main_page.blade.php

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li ><a class="lispan" href="#home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
<li><a class="lispan" href="#play_match"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> How to play</a></li>
<li><a class="lispan" href="#match_schedule"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Schedule</a></li>
<li><a class="lispan" href="{{route('register')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
@if (Auth::guest())
<li><a class="lispan" href="{{route('login')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
@else
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
<li><a class="lispan" href="{{ route('logout')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
@endif
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your code seems correct, Can you please get the output of  {{ Auth::user()->name }} ? what is the result?

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Comment: I have the same problem, I created a new laravel (6) app, added laravel/ui installed npm, did npm run dev, used the bootstrap preset .. everything works just fine out of the box (no composer or console errors) but clicking on the username doesn't nothing = no dropdown with a logout link

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel 5.7 onwards,then there is a very simplistic way of doing this.Just modify your code like below :

@auth

```
// The user is authenticated...

<li><a class="lispan" href="{{ route('logout')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
```

@endauth

@guest

```
// The user is not authenticated...

<li><a class="lispan" href="{{route('login')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

@endguest

Answer (score -1):

Check with `Auth::check()` and make sure you do cache clear by `php artisan cache:clear`

```
@if (Auth::check())
    // logged in
@else
    // guest mode             
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method but this method also is not working

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach according to Laravel 5.6 would be

```
@auth
 <li><a class="lispan" href="{{ route('logout')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
@endauth

@guest
 <li><a class="lispan" href="{{route('login')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
@endguest
```

For more help https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade

Answer (score -1):

If you're at latest version of Laravel (5.6+) you can try the below also:

```
@auth
// The user is authenticated and show logout
@endauth

@guest
// The user is not authenticated and show login
@endguest
```

For more details @ [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade)